# Product of a Lie ideal with a subalgebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

Let $L$ be a Lie algebra over $A$, $I$ a Lie ideal in $L$, $K$ a subalgebra of $L$. The goal is to show that $[I,K]$ (the $A$-submodule generated by $[i,k]$ for $i \in I$ and $k \in K$) is a Lie subalgebra as well. If
$$ S = \{ [i,k] : i \in I, k \in K\},$$
I believe that by bilinearity of the bracket it suffices to show that $[S,S] \subseteq [I,K]$. So take two elements $i, i' \in I$, $k, k' \in K$. The goal is to then show
$$ [[i,k],[i',k']] \in [I,K].$$
This is where I'm lost and would like a hint as to where to go. My initial idea is to use the Jacobi identity to get
$$ [[i,k],[i',k']] = -[i',[k',[i,k]]] - [k',[[i,k],i']].$$
Since $I$ is an ideal, $[i,k] \in I$, $[[i,k],i'] \in I$, and so $-[k',[[i,k],i']] \in [I,K]$. The idea then is to show that $-[i', [k',[i,k]]] \in [I,K]$. Use the Jacobi identity again to get

$$-[k', [i,k]] = [i,[k,k']] + [k,[k',i]], $$
so that
$$ -[i',[k',[i,k]]] = [i',[i,[k,k']]] + [i',[k,[k',i]]].$$
Trying the Jacobi identity again gets us
$$[i',[i,[k,k']]] = -[i, [[k,k'],i']] - [[k,k'],[i',i]], $$
$$[i', [k,[k',i]]] = -[k,[[k',i],i']] - [[k',i],[i',k]].  $$
It seems like this is going nowhere. If $K$ was assumed to also be a Lie ideal, then this result follows easily (in fact, $[I,K]$ would be an ideal), but otherwise it doesn't seem like there's a way to rearrange things with just the Jacobi identity so that we get a linear combination of elements in $[I,K]$.

I've alternatively thought about just approaching it at the level of showing
$$ [[I,K],[I,K]] \subseteq [I,K].$$
Here, we use the Jacobi identity to note
$$ [[I,K],[I,K]] \subseteq [[I,[I,K]],K] + [[K,[I,K]],I].$$
Now use the fact that $I$ is an ideal to get
$$ [I,[I,K]] \subseteq I,$$
so we have
$$ [[I,K],[I,K]] \subseteq [I,K] + [[K,[I,K]],I].$$
The goal here is to show
$$[[K,[I,K]],I] \subseteq [I,K],$$
which seems to require
$$ [K,[I,K]] \subseteq K.$$
If
$$ [I,K] \subseteq N_L(K) = \{x \in L : [K,x] \subseteq K\},$$
then the result follows, but I don't see why this is necessarily true either.

Comment: I would also just be happy with someone letting me know whether this fact is true without a proof. It would be good for me to play with it longer, but I want to make sure it's actually going somewhere.

Comment: The statement your're proving is not true, you'll easily find an example with $I=L$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer after the fact.

Consider $L = \mathfrak{gl}(2, \mathbb{C})$, $I = L$, $K = \mathfrak{d}(2, \mathbb{C})$ (the space of $2 \times 2$ diagonal matrices). The bracket on $L$ is $[A,B] = AB - BA$ (the commutator). The first thing to notice is that we have

$$ \left[\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} x & 0 \\ 0 & y \end{pmatrix} \right] = \begin{pmatrix}0 & b(y-x) \\ c(x-y) & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$

So $[I,K]$ is going to be linear combinations of off-diagonal matrices. Notice that for two off-diagonal matrices, we have

$$ \left[ \begin{pmatrix} 0 & a \\ b & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & x \\ y & 0 \end{pmatrix}\right] = \begin{pmatrix}ay & 0 \\ 0 & xb \end{pmatrix} \notin [I,K].$$

This means $[I,K]$ can't be an algebra.