# The commutator of a Lie subalgebra and a Lie ideal is a again a Lie subalgebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

I found the following claim in [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1905712/commutator-of-two-lie-subalgebras):

> Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a Lie algebra, let $\mathfrak{h}$ be a Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}$ and let $I$ be a Lie ideal of $\mathfrak{g}$.
> Then the commutator space $[\mathfrak{h}, I]$ is again a Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}$.

I’ve been trying to prove this claim by showing that for all $x, x' \in \mathfrak{h}$ and $y, y' \in I$ the commutator $[[x,y],[x',y']]$ is again contained in $[\mathfrak{h}, I]$. For this I’ve tried to repeatedly use the Jacobi identity, but I’m only going around in circles.

Comment: It's not true. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3806183/96384